# PHP creating dynamic objects and php.ini settings

Tags: php, variables, object, dynamic, objectname

I have a strange problem with creating dynamic objects.

On my local server with PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 this code works fine:

```
$sObjName = 'field_xyz';
$o = $oVendor->{$sObjName};
print_r($o);                //prints the object "$oVendor->field_xyz"
```

But on my live server with PHP 5.3.13 the same code doesnt work.
I cant create a dynamic object.

This code also doesnt work on my live server:

```
$oVendor->$sObjName
```

Otherwise this code works on both servers:

```
$a = "Hello";
$$a = "World";
echo "$a ${$a}";      //prints out "Hello World"
```

I would guess that this is a php.ini setting problem but I really dont know.

**Local Server vs: Live Server**

**Local:**

- Real Server
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
- Suhosin Patch 0.9.10
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

**Live:**

- Virtual Server
- PHP 5.3.13
- No Suhosin
- Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.13 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o

Comment: If that code doesn't work on your live server then something is seriously broken.

Comment: [**Can't confirm**](http://3v4l.org/N7EoG). What *doesn't* work? Do you get an error? Does it silently fail? Does it crash PHP? Does your server force reboot?

Comment: What's different between your test and production systems? PHP versions? Suhosin?....

Comment: @h2ooooooo  There is no error and no notice and no php crash. My live server just doesnt create this new object and so the print_r() prints nothing.

Comment: @user3111283 What does `var_dump` output? `var_dump` ALWAYS has to output something. Whether it's NULL, false, true, etc. etc. Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on?

Comment: @symcbean  I edited the original post for differences

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes i have "E_ALL". `var_dump($oVendor->{$sObjName})` outputs "NULL"

Comment: @user3111283 And `var_dump($oVendor)`? (update OP with it)

Comment: @h2ooooooo  Ohh i feel very stupid right now. `var_dump($oVendor)` showed me that the object `$oVendor->field_xyz` is "NULL" in my live system and not an own object like in my local system. Its an application problem

Comment: @user3111283 No worries - it's what we're here for. `var_dump` is **incredibly** useful for debugging. I use it all the time.